# Connecting to an SQL server using a different domain account

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, sql-server-2012

I am currently trying to connect to an SQL server using a different domain/username that has permissions for querying the server. Here is the powershell just to test whether or not the connection works,

```
$connectionString = "Server=<my_server>;Database=<db>;User ID=<domain>\<testuser>;Password=<password>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$connection.Open();
$connection.Close();
```

I end up getting this error.

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user '<testuser>'.

I am certain that the username and password is correct. As that's what's in the Client Settings.

But I am wondering if there's additional arguments needed to add to the connection string?

Comment: Including a User ID and Password in a connection string causes it to use SQL Login authentication and that won't work with Windows/Domain credentials. You'll need to use Impersonation in PowerShell to change the Windows/Domain account under which the SQL Connection gets made (with `Integrated Security=true` in the connection string).

Comment: You'll need to run the PS script under the desired domain account (e.g. using RUNAS) and specify `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string.

Comment: @DanGuzman unfortunately the domain account that I need to query the DB server, can't login to the server that i'm running the script from. 

And my account cant login to the  DB server. Would that mean this task is not possible or am I wrong?

Comment: @okmanl, SQL authentication would be easier if you don't have the ability to allow the domain account to login locally.

Comment: Start PowerShell with RunAs /netonly, the program will execute on your local computer as the user you are currently logged on as, but any connections to other computers on the network will be made using the user account specified. Without /netonly everything will run under the user account specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task needed to be automated, but the solution was to connect to the server using -Credentials to login to the desired user.

```
$computerName = 'SQLServer' 

$adminUsername = 'username'
$adminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$adminCreds = New-Object PSCredential $adminUsername, $adminPassword

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
$SQLServer = "sqlserver"
$SQLDBName = "database"
$uid ="account"
$pwd = "password"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT TOP (12) [attribute1]
 FROM [table].[dbo].[AAG00200];"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

} -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $adminCreds
```